# Search the specfic substring with a pattern format having last occurrence within a raw text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string like:

```
Location: FD130 New York GA Unit Serial Purchase Order Sales Order Make Model Amount Tax Total 12345566 Location: FD130 Roswell GA Unit Serial Purchase Order Sales Order Make Model Amount Tax Total 0130029964
```

When i trying regex like to get the location of specified serial no.(34573).
Regex: `'Location:(.*)?Unit(.*?)0130029964`

Then it giving the whole string string with location and ending with 34573.

The expected output is `FD130 New York GA` when i pass `0130029964` serial id.

Is there any function in python for getting the first backward sub-string `location` from given serial no.

Comment: The first group is giving the whole string as it is.

Comment: `r'Location:\s*(\S+)[^.?!]*unit[^.?!]*\b34573\b'`? See https://regex101.com/r/AEpqfC/1

Comment: Actually i tried this regex it giving the whole string as starting from location and ending with 34573 id. i am told that regex won't work here.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/1WyKhM. With `m = re.search(rx, text, re.I)`, you get `Delhi`. Maybe you can use `r"Location:\s*([^.?!]*?)\s*format\s+unit[^.?!]*\b34573\b"`, too, see https://ideone.com/P04Clw

Comment: Try `\blocation:\s*((?:(?!location:|unit|format).)+) (?:format )?unit (?:(?!location:).)+\b0130029964\b` See https://regex101.com/r/26X0X0/1 and https://regex101.com/r/JM47JR/1

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `Location:(.*?)Unit(.*?)0130029964`? Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/DuZTEZ/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match location unit the first occurrence of `unit` using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) approach to not cross matching either `location:` `unit` or `format`.

Then optionally match `format`  and match till the specific number without crossing matching `location:` again.

```
\blocation:\s*((?:(?!location:|unit|format).)+) (?:format )?unit (?:(?!location:).)+\b12345566\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZmZzI/1)